# When I used a tree example from Extjs 5 to make my own tree. I will get a Cannot read property 'items' of null

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null

the error is inside initComponent

my error show when i use my xtype: 'treepanel', i think the error inside the initComponent

```
userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
Ext.define('TutorialApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend    : 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires  :
               [
                 'TutorialApp.view.main.MainController',
                 'TutorialApp.view.main.MainModel',
                 'TutorialApp.store.MainTree'
               ],
    xtype     : 'app-main',
    controller: 'main',
    plugins   : 'viewport',
    viewModel : 
                {
                   type : 'main'
                },
    layout    : {
                   type : 'border'
                },
    items     : 
                [
                 {
                     xtype       : 'panel',
                     bind        : 
                                    {
                                        title: '{name} '+userName+''
                                    },
                     region      : 'west',
                     html        : '<ul><li>This area is commonly used for navigation, for example, using a "tree" component.</li></ul>',
                     width       : 250,
                     split       : true,
                     collapsible : true,`enter code here`
                     bbar        : 
                                  [
                                   {
                                       text    : 'Button',
                                       handler : 'onClickButton'
                                   }
                                  ],
                     items       : [
                                    {
                                      xtype       : 'treepanel',
                                      rootVisible : true,
                                      store       : 'MainTree',
                                      initComponent: function() 
                                      {
                                          // declare store
                                          this.store = new  TutorialApp.store.MainTree();
                                          // declare all items 
                                          this.items = [
                                                          {
                                                              title: 'Tree'
                                                          }
                                                        ];
                                          this.callParent();
                                      }
                                    }
                                   ]
                 },
                 {
                    region  : 'center',
                    xtype   : 'tabpanel',
                    items   :
                             [
                              {
                                    title : 'Tab 1',
                                    html  : '<h2>Content appropriate for the current navigation.</h2>'
                              }
                             ]
                 }
                ]
});
```

This tree store comes 
its a simple store

```
Ext.define('TutorialApp.store.MainTree', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore', 
    root: {
            text: 'Root',
            expanded: true,
            children: [
                {
                    text: 'Child 1',
                    leaf: true
                },
                {
                    text: 'Child 2',
                    leaf: true
                },
                {
                    text: 'Child 3',
                    expanded: true,
                    children: [
                        {
                            text: 'Grandchild',
                            leaf: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
});
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0):

> i think the error inside the initComponent

`initComponent` is not really supposed to be passed as a config option. If you need to apply your own logic in `initComponent`, you have to derive your own class. So, instead of:

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    rootVisible: true,
    store: 'MainTree',
    initComponent: function() {
        // declare store
        this.store = new  TutorialApp.store.MainTree();
        // declare all items
        this.items = [
            {
                title: 'Tree'
            }
        ];
        this.callParent();
    }
}
```

define your own tree panel:

```
Ext.define('MyTreePanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mytreepanel',
    initComponent: function() {
        // declare store
        this.store = new  TutorialApp.store.MainTree();
        // declare all items
        this.items = [
            {
                title: 'Tree'
            }
        ];
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

and use its xtype:

```
{
    xtype: 'mytreepanel',
    rootVisible: true,
    store: 'MainTree'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer i write your code no error at my console. the title show up but the tree doesn't show .

Comment: Well the question was about the *"Cannot read property 'items' of null"* error, wasn't it? I pointed you where the error was.
Now, the tree being empty is a separate issue. It's empty because the only child you specified to your "tree" bears the title *only* and is not a tree at all. I guess you needed to specify the `title` on the `treepanel` itself, not on its child. In this case you won't need your `initComponent` at all.